# How to tell if the last function was called in a class: Python

Tags: python, function, call

I have a Python class similar to the following:

```
class BuildSentence(object):

    def __init__(self, intro):
        self.sentence = intro

    def name(self, na):
        self.sentence += "; my name is %s" % (na)

    def surname(self, su):
        self.sentence += "; my surname is %s" % (su)

    def age(self, ag):
        self.sentence += "; I am %d years old" % (ag)

    def final_sentence(self):
        self.sentence += "."
        return do_something_with(self.sentence)
```

I want the `final_sentence'` function called automatically **only** when all the required functions are finished.  The 'final_sentence' function does not necessarily return a string, it may be an integer or list.  I am not sure if it is possible to identify the last function called?

For instance:

```
s = BuildSentence("Hello")
answer = s.name("Foo").age(40)
```

Should 'do_something_with':

```
Hello; my is Foo; I am 40 years old.
```

Comment: You almost certainly have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can maintain a state for this right?

Comment: Give the class a `_repr_` method that returns final sentence.

Comment: Why do you want use a class for this? Why not just use a simple function: `build_sentence(intro, name, surname, age)`?

Comment: also note that your methods are inconsistent... if `print(s.surname("Bar"))` should work the way you want it to, it must return a `str`. but the way you want to be able to chain `s.name("Foo").age(50)`; `.name` must return `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__str__`-Method, which is automatically called whenever a string is needed.

```
class BuildSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, intro):
        self.sentence = intro
        self.templates = {
            'name': "; my name is %s",
            'surname': "; my surname is %s",
            'age': "; I am %d years old",
        }

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def set(value):
            self.sentence += self.templates.pop(attr) % value
            return self
        return set

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sentence + '.'
```

Example:

```
>>> print(BuildSentence('Hello').name('Tim').age(45))
Hello; my name is Tim; I am 45 years old.
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the last method to `__str__`

```
class BuildSentence(object):

    def __init__(self, intro):
        self.sentence = intro

    def name(self, na):
        self.sentence += "; my name is %s" % (na)

    def surname(self, su):
        self.sentence += "; my surname is %s" % (su)

    def age(self, ag):
        self.sentence += "; I am %d years old" % (ag)

    def __str__(self):
        self.sentence += "."
        return (self.sentence)
```

Call

```
s = BuildSentence("Hello")
s.name("Foo") 
s.age(50)
s.surname(50)
print( s )
```

Output

```
Hello; my name is Foo; I am 50 years old; my surname is 50.
```